# Progress bar while writing text to output file

Tags: vb.net

I have a program to pull data from a datagrid view and then export it to a csv file.
I want to be able to add a progress bar while writing the text to output file. So far I  don't want to use the timer since its not very accurate.

Here is my code to write it to a text file:

```
Dim writer As TextWriter = New StreamWriter(OutputFile)


        writer.WriteLine("   ")
        For i As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 2 Step +1

            For j As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.Columns.Count - 1 Step +1

                writer.Write(vbTab & DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(j).Value.ToString() & vbTab)

            Next




        Next
        writer.Close()


        MsgBox( " file has been created")
```

Any help with the progress bar will be appreciated. 
Thanks

Comment: `ProgressBars` aren't magic. They are simply a representation of a ratio. They just display the progress that you calculate. It's up to you to work out how to calculate the progress. You'll need to put some thought into that. If you were doing it manually, how would you perform that calculation?

Comment: Is there some data source behind the DataGridView? Roughly how many rows and columns are there in the DGV? There could be a way to make it fast enough to not need a progress bar.

Comment: What would the ProgressBar will do? That's undefined (e.g. tracks text length, based on calculating something and showing up, etc.)

Comment: @ LinuX Man The progress bar should just display progress while exporting the text file to my computer from the data grid

Comment: @ jmcilhinney  manually I am trying increment a variable current_count by 1 and then Current_Count / Src_Count * 100

Comment: @ Andrew Morton it doesn't have a specific number of rows and colomns, it pulls data from a datagrid view which displays data from a database then exports to text file.

Comment: @Krushan Where does the DataGridView get its data from? Please try to give us enough information to help you, because if you don't then we can't ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the maximum of the ProgressBar and then increment it's current value. I hope that answers your question. 
(Note: you don't need to add "Step + 1". for loops increment is by default set to 1)

```
Dim writer As TextWriter = New StreamWriter(OutputFile)

ProgressBar1.Maximum = DataGridView1.Rows.Count * DataGridView1.Columns.Count
Dim progress As Integer = 0

writer.WriteLine("   ")
For i As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 2

   For j As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.Columns.Count - 1

       writer.Write(vbTab & DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(j).Value.ToString() & vbTab)
       ProgressBar1.Value = progress
       progress += 1

    Next
Next

writer.Close()

MsgBox("file has been created")
```

[vb.net](/questions/tagged/vb.net)

Comment: Thanks Bruno, this helped me solve the problem. Thanks for the tiop on step too.

Comment: While the accepted answer should work and solve your problem, I think it is not optimal at all. Because accessing (and scanning) UI controls is significantly slower than accessing in-memory data and will make your UI unresponsive while this routine is running. The odds are that your DGV is already bound to a datatable, then simply export the contents of the datatable. And if you don't already have a bound datatable it would be a good idea to have one or I am wondering how you save and persist the data.